# Comparing images and removing similar images per every row

Tags: python-3.x, image, machine-learning, image-processing

I need to compare 400000  images and remove similar images. I will have around 100000 id’s  with multiple images with different size in one file. I would like to create two columns id and images and for every id remove similar images. If one id has 10 images but only two are different I would like to have only two images for that id. I’m searching for same easy way to do this in python.

Comment: You need to think rather carefully about what you mean by *"similar"*. Is a 100x100 pixel black JPEG similar to a 100x100 pixel black PNG? The file contents will differ completely. What about an 8-bit fully red image and a 16-bit fully red image - are they similar? The files will be totally different. What about an 8-bit 100x100 solid red PNG and another one with the same content but saved 1 second later? They will have different checksums/hashes because the creation time is embedded.

Comment: I will use JPEG only and by similar I mean if I have two images in one row or let's say id nuber 1 has two images showing the same product but the different pixel size...or I have images showing product let's say bottle 2 images are showing front and 3 images back of the bottle I would like to have only two images for that row or id. I don't know can I use some correlation when it comes to images?

Comment: I will not use pixel black JPG

Comment: I found a simple solution with imagehash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import imagehash

hash1 = imagehash.phash(Image.open('image_a.jpg'))
print(hash1)

hash2 = imagehash.phash(Image.open('image_b.jpg'))
print(hash2)


hash1 == hash2
```

output

e5969a1b256e8cc9

ebd49312f02e862f

False